# What exactly does it mean to run command via shell and without in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, shell, spawn

I don't understand what it means to run command without a shell. I came from Windows OS where all commands run via shell e.g. cmd.exe, powershell. Maybe, I'm mistaken and commands can run without a shell.

Consider this code:

```
spawn('some-cmd', ['some-args'], {shell:true})
```

vs

```
spawn('some-cmd', ['some-args'])
```

So, what does it mean running command **without** a shell? 
Is this concept relates to Node.js only or belongs to OS(Windows, Linux)? Pros and cons of running command with/without a shell?

Comment: How do you think cmd.exe runs programs?

Comment: If you run with a shell, it will do all the normal stuff like expanding wildcard filenames, passing in environment variables and looking up executables you execute along your PATH. If you run without a shell, it won't.